# Google Analytics custom product definitions: dimensions or metrics?

Tags: google-analytics, ecommerce

I would like to track Custom products Definitions with Enhanced Ecommerce tracking in Google Analytics.

I have created some Custom Dimensions for my products:

- **Product Discount (%)**: % discount of the product at the time it was bought. Example value: 18
- **Original Price**: The original price of the product before discount. Example value: 184
- **Product Discount End**: Number of days before the discount ends - *I would like to analyze whether my customers buy more when the deal is about to end or not.* Example value: 2

After reading the article about Custom Definitions at Google Analytics Help Center (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) I'm not sure whether these product description values wouldn't be better to track as Custom Metrics.

Should I use custom dimensions or metrics for product descriptions above?